# Dispatch action in injectedJavascript of Android device WebView in React Native not working

Tags: react-native, webview, android-webview

i have 1 html and i need get all src attribute of image tag. Everything is running perfect(iOS, Android Virtual machine, iOS device), but only Android Device, I can't get src attribute!! Please help me! Thanks!!

> My WebView

```
render() {
    const { source, style, ...otherProps } = this.props;
    const { realContentHeight } = this.state;
    const html = source.html;
    const number = this.addHeight(html);
    const addHeightMore = number * 220;

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View 
                style={{

                    paddingHorizontal: 5,
                }}
            >
                <WebView
                    {...otherProps}
                    source={{ 
                        html:`
                             <head></head>
                             <body style="font-size: ${sizeText}; text-align: left; padding: 5">
                                  ${templates[this.props.template](html)}
                             </body>
                            `
                    }}
                    onLoad={this.onLoad.bind(this)}
                    injectedJavaScript={this.injectedJavaScript()}
                    mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
                    onMessage={this.onMessage.bind(this)}
                    scrollEnabled={false}
                    style={[{ height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? realContentHeight : realContentHeight < screenHeight ? screenHeight : realContentHeight + addHeightMore}, style]}
                    javaScriptEnabled
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

> injectedJavascript()

```
injectedJavaScript() {

    return ` 
        ${this.hackBefore()}

        function dispatchAction(action, params) {
            window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                action,
                params,
            }));
        };

        var imgs = [];

        document.querySelectorAll('img:not(.emoji):not(.embedded-img):not(.embedded-btn)').forEach(function (img, index) {
            var src = img.getAttribute('src');
            imgs.push(src);

            img.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                dispatchAction('openGallery', {
                    index: index,
                });
            });
        });

        dispatchAction('addImages', {
            imgs: imgs,
        });

        ${this.hackAfter()}
    `
}
```

> hackBefore

hackBefore() {
        return Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
        
            `(function(){
            var originalPostMessage = window.postMessage;
            var patchedPostMessage = function(message, targetOrigin, transfer) {
                originalPostMessage(message, targetOrigin, transfer);
            };
            patchedPostMessage.toString = function() {
                return String(Object.hasOwnProperty).replace('hasOwnProperty', 'postMessage');
            };
            window.postMessage = patchedPostMessage;`
        :
        
            `if (window.postMessage.length !== 1) {
                window.postMessage = function(msg) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log('window.postMessage not ready');
                    window.postMessage(msg);
                    }, 500);
                }
            }`

    }

> hackAfter()

```
hackAfter() {
    return Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '})();' : ''
}
```

> onMessage()

```
onMessage(event) {
    const { action, params } = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data)

    switch (action) {
    case 'heightCaculated': {
        return this.setState({
        realContentHeight: params.height,
        isRendering: false,
        })
    }
    case 'addImages': {
        this.props.resetImages()
        // Prefetch image
        params.imgs.map(img => Image.prefetch(img))
        return this.props.addImages(params.imgs)
    }

    case 'openGallery':
        return navigator.navigate('Gallery', {
            index: params.index,
        })


    default:
        return null
    }
}
```

> redux

```
   export default connect(null, {
    addImages,
    resetImages,
})(WebViewAutoHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

When running your application on an Android device, in production, you must build your HTML file to the Android asset directory - `android/app/src/main/assets/index.html`

Your `WebView` source should then point to this file, `file:///android_asset/index.html`. But only on certain conditions

If you are on Android, and you're running in Production the source should be `file:///android_asset/index.html`. Else, point your source to your local HTML file.

Here's an example, I am not sure how your project is structured but you can cherrypick what you need.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, WebView } from 'react-native';

import localFile from '../index.html';

const MyWebView extends React.Component {
  isAndroid = () => Platform.OS === "android"
  isDev = () => __DEV__
  getSource = () => {
    if(this.isAndroid() && !this.isDev()) {
      return { uri: 'file:///android_asset/index.html' };
    }
    return localFile
  }
  render() {
    <WebView
      source={this.getSource()}
    />
  }
}
```